# Linked List Cycle

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to write a simple linked list cycle on python, however there is a bug I couldn't figure out why.
My code is something like this:

```
class ListNode:
   def __init__(self, x):
      self.val = x
      self.next = None
class Solution:
   def hasCycle(self, head: ListNode) -> bool:
      slow=head;
      fast=head;
      while slow and fast:
         slow=slow.next;
         fast=fast.next.next;
         if slow==fast:
             return True
      return False
```

It indeed comes with an error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

However when I try with the online solution which is:

```
class Solution:
def hasCycle(self, head: ListNode) -> bool:
    
    slow = head
    fast = head
    
    while fast and fast.next:
        slow = slow.next
        fast = fast.next.next
        
        if slow == fast:
            return True
    return False
```

It turns out to be true, I don't understand why there is a different.

Shouldn't slow and fast sound more reasonable than fast and fast.next? Could anyone solve my confusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the error is that the body of the loop has this line:

```
fast = fast.next.next
```

This can only work without error when you are sure that `fast` is *not* the last node in the list. `fast.next` must also be a Node instance (and not `None`), as otherwise `fast.next.next` translates to `None.next`, which obviously is invalid. So to avoid this from happening, the `while` condition should also verify that `fast.next` is not `None`.

On the other hand, in the first code snippet you check whether `slow` is not `None`, but that is unnecessary, because `slow` will never arrive faster at the end of the list than `fast`, so it is enough to focus on `fast` in the `while` condition. If `fast` is not `None`, then you can be sure that `slow` is not `None` either, as it never surpasses `fast`.

Comment: Thx! I finally understand the concept after your clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

please check the code

```
while fast and fast.next:
```

and

```
while slow and fast:
```

Comment: This is what i am confusing... why the upper one works while the bottom one doesn't?

Comment: while fast and fast.next, this sentence i understand as current node and next node, but they're in the same pointer(lets call it right pointer)
while slow and fast, I understand it as left pointer and right pointer, shouldn't they will be able to find whether it is a linked-list cycle?